# In SAS, How Do I Create/Alter Postgres tables?

Tags: postgresql, sas

I have SAS code that will write to a postgres table if it is already created but still empty. How can I create/alter a postgres table from SAS (or using a script that pulls in SAS macro variables) if it does not exist or already has data? The number of fields may change. Currently, I use the filename option along with the pipe to write to the postgres file.

```
filename pgout pipe %unquote(%bquote(')/data/dwight/IFS6.2/app/PLANO/sas_to_psql.sh
                             %bquote(")&f_out_schema.%bquote(").&file_name.
                             %bquote(')
                             )
;
```

I've tried using this version, but it does not work:

```
filename pgout pipe %unquote(%bquote(')/data/dwight/IFS6.2/app/PLANO/sas_to_psql.sh
                            %bquote('')CREATE TABLE mdo_backend.fob_id_desc 
                                       SELECT * FROM &library_name..&file_name.
                            %bquote(")&f_out_schema.%bquote(").&file_name./('')/
                            %bquote(')
                            )
;
```

This is the script I use:

```
LOAD_TO_PSQL.SH


#!/bin/bash

. /data/projects/ifs/psql/config.sh 

psql -d $DB -tAq -c "COPY $1 FROM STDIN USING DELIMITERS '|'"
```

Comment: Any particular reason you don't connect to the postgres database directly (using ACCESS to POSTGRESQL or OLEDB/ODBC)?

Comment: The database is not ours. We're running jobs for clients who do not have SAS, so we take the postgress data (and data formats) convert it into the appropriate SAS and job formats, run the jobs, then retranslate the results and send them back to postgres in their desired format.

Comment: I've been able to pipe the delimited data directly into a datastep, but there are no templates on their end to which I can write. I need a way to create a template/alter a table automatically, and based on two macrovars which carry the format of the table. I have to do it this way because I won't know the format of the table until after the SAS job is run.

Comment: Not sure I follow; you're clearly running postgres (given `psql` in the shell script), so I don't see why you couldn't get SAS to connect to it.  In any event, you may want to run the process, create the .sh file, and post an example of it (perhaps run this with some dummy data) so that it's evident whether the problem is in Postgresql (i.e., the piped file is not working the way you want it to) or in SAS (i.e., you're not writing out the piped file you'd like).

Comment: SAS will connect to it, but it will _not_ create the table with what I have written. The first filename statement will correctly write if the file has already been created. If the postgres file has not already been created, the first filename statement will not work. The second filename statement is my attempt to create the postgres table before writing to it, but that does not work. What is wrong with the second filename statement? Why does it not create a table to write to?

Comment: Here is the sample code:

Comment: %macro ifs_to_psql;
filename pgout pipe %unquote(
    %bquote(')/data/dwight/IFS6.2/app/PLANO/sas_to_psql.sh
    %bquote('')CREATE TABLE mdo_backend.fob_id_desc 
               SELECT * FROM landing.fob_id_desc
    %bquote(")mdo_backend%bquote(").fob_id_desc/('')/
    %bquote(')
);
data work.list;
    if 0 then set landing.fob_id_desc;
    stop;
run;
data _null_;
set landing.fob_id_desc;
file pgout;
put %_format_list_(%_vars_list_(data=work.list), between = %str( '|' ));
run;
%mend ifs_to_psql;
%ifs_to_psql;

Comment: Message(s) received from the pipe command:
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `/data/dwight/IFS6.2/app/PLANO/sas_to_psql.sh    'CREATE TABLE mdo_backend.fob_id_desc                SELECT 
2                                                          The SAS System                           09:18 Thursday, February 9, 2017

* FROM landing.fob_id_desc    "mdo_backend".fob_id_desc/(')/    '

Comment: Use `proc export` to export the data files and then use PostgreSQL (`psql`) scripts to import the data.  Generating SQL scripts from bash scripts generated from SAS macros is a house of cards.  Also you're missing an AS in your SQL: `CREATE TABLE tablename AS SELECT * FROM...`

Comment: Also, rather than trying to load into an existing table directly from a flat file, it is common practice to `copy` the flat file to a temporary staging table and then insert to the existing table, which allows you to transform the data as needed.